# In need of a Push service for Laravel mobile app

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, laravel, push-notification

I am building an iOS/Android app using Laravel as backend and now I need a push service.

I need to push out two types of notifications, when the app is running/background and one when its closed.

I dont mind using two types of services, I mostly want one that is easy to implement into Laravel.

I have already looked at **Urban airship**, but it seems hard to implement this with Laravel - Might just be my mad skills.

**Pusher**, looks easy to implement with laravel, and can only handle in-app/background pushes. But their smallest plan only support 100 connections which seems a little. - *100 logged in users?*

**Parse** seems to work, but if I understand their api I also need to log users into parse's API.

So please share your experiences on push services using Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

> in-app

- **[Pusher](https://pusher.com/)** allows 100 users connected *simultaneously*. So if you `unbind` the channel on `appstate` going to background, you should be fine up to 400-500 users (in my case, I had 2000+ users before I had to upgrade my account to startup). You can find out more about their pricing plans here: [Pricing Plans](https://pusher.com/pricing)

> background

- **[Parse](https://parseplatform.github.io/)**: as of writing this, their status is "service is now shut down".
- **[Urban Airship](https://go.urbanairship.com)**: I found their library the easiest to implement, and they have a ton of customization that you can apply to your notification (*including notification actions*).

All that being said, I had a hard time finding a library to for laravel to push the notification for **Urban Airship**. The only one I found is [php-library2](https://github.com/urbanairship/php-library2), but it's not supported any more, so use with caution.